# Change in asp.net page life cycle event

Tags: asp.net

Has there been any change in page life cycle event in asp.net 3.5(I mean some addition or any modification in the exisitng one)?

Sorry to ask in this way as because recently in an interview I have been asked by an interviewer. I dare to ask him the answer for this even after the interview!

If the asnwer is yes, kindly give some detailing about that; even a tutorial link will also do if no explicit explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that he wanted to hear about the integrated AJAX support that was added in ASP.NET 3.5, and the way [partial-page rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386573.aspx) supports it.  Just a guess, because there are no new Page events as such.